# how to customise toolbar in Leaflet.Draw plugin?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, leaflet-draw

I downloaded the `Draw.js` and one ccs file to use the Leaflet.Draw plugin, but now I need to customise the toolbar (i.e want only polygon and marker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw : {
        position : 'topleft',
        polyline : false,
        rectangle : false,
        circle : false,
        polygon: {
            // polygon draw options here
        },
        marker: {
            // marker options here
        }
    },
    edit : false
});

map.addControl(drawControl);
```

see [here for draw options](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawoptions)